# db result to php array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to use morris area chart dynamicly
from my sql query I get the following result

```
period  |  item  |  amount  
------  |  ----  |  ------  
20170801  |  iphone  |  327  
20170801  |  ipad  |  278  
20170801  |  ipod  |  125  
20170802  |  iphone  |  528  
20170802  |  ipad  |  325  
20170802  |  ipod  |  250
```

etc

now I need to store this in an array like this

```
data: [{
        period: '20170801',
        iphone: 327,
        ipad: 278,
        ipod: 125
    }, {
        period: '20170802',
        iphone: 528,
        ipad: 325,
        itouch: 250
    }, ...]
```

I am using a while loop through the table for each date it needs to create a new object. For a date in an object it needs to add an element to that object.

I have absolutely no clue how to achieve this

Comment: You can use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) with your DB array

Comment: I think this is a javascript issue, because you are talking about morris charts, please show how are you trying to process that data on js.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

class test {
    private $period = '';
    private $item = '';
    private $amount = '';

    public function __construct($period, $item, $amount) {
        $this->period = $period;
        $this->item = $item;
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }
}

$obj = [
    new test('20170801', 'iphone', '327'),
    new test('20180801', 'iphone2', '328')
];

var_dump($obj);
```

But most usefull use ORM and after you get data - serialize it to string via php function "json_encode"

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: i do not think this does what it needs to do, look at my table and at my array

Comment: You have not array because - (array it is a "[]")  but this quotes "{}"mean that you have a object

Comment: I think his example is missing array `[ ]` anyway, or else it makes no sense. We can show you a better example if you show some code how you store the data in php or whatever you have.

Comment: Changed it in the original post. i have no code yet because i do not have a clue how to achieve this as i said before

Answer (score -1):

Ok since you have no idea how to start I coded a little script to get you started:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
$result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$data = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$json = json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($json);
```

You have to change the database server data and you table name in SQL query, other then that it should just output the whole table data in JSON format. If you want to join all data from teh same date you have to add soem more logic, but that might cause duplicate properties.